# About importing a Python module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I imported a module in python, but I found out that I needed to import this module in a different way for some functions.
for example

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
```

I am confused. At first, we import the entire module by saying `import tkinter`. Why do we have to say `from tkinter import ttk` again

I did

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
stil=tkinter.Style()
```

but chatgpt did

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
stil=tkinter.ttk.Style()
```

Comment: Depends what wanted... If you want to use specific function from the sub-module within `tkinter`, i.e. `ttk` you'd need to import it seperately using `from` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Modules are nothing but python files containing classes and functions. A module can contain only functions also. Once you understand how the module is structurized, you'll understand how to import them.

Follow the hierarchy:

```
                          Module
           (a python file named 'module_name.py'):
         (Assume that this module has three classes)
                              |
                              |
          ------------------------------------------------
          |                    |                          |
    Class_A              Class_B                        Class_C
(assume class-A has    (assume class_B has             (assume class-C
  3 functions)          2 functions)                  has 1 function)
  |                      |                                 |
  |--> method_1          |--method_1                       |
  |                      |                              method-1
  |--> method_2          |-- method_2
  |
  |--> method_3
```

I've used the word 'method' for functions inside the class for the sake of understanding.

Since the file name is module_name.py, here module_name is the name of the module. So we should import module_name module.

As per hierarchy, this is how we call:

Now you're importing:
method 1:

```
#if you want to import the complete module
import module_name

# Now if you want to use method_2 of class_A in the above module
some_variable = module_name.class_A.method_2()

# If you want to use class_B in the above module:
some_variable = module_name.class_B
```

In the above example, though we have imported the entire module, We didn't specify 'all' while importing. We can use all the classes and functions by importing this way. but, Since we didn't specify 'all' , we should call the classes along with module_name separated by dots.

But there is an 2nd option. while importing itself when we mention 'all', then we should not mention module_name while calling. for using all we use the * symbol. That is 'from module_name import *' means 'from module_name import all'. So, if we follow this way:

```
from module_name import *

#Now to call method_3 in class_A

some_variable = class_A.method_3()

#Note module_name is not added to call, because * is used.
```

The third option is: You don't want to use all the functions and classes in the module. Instead for the entire program, you want to use only method_2 from class_B, Now you don't need to import the entire module. Only that particular class alone can be imported

```
 #if only method_2 of class_B for the entire program

 from module_name import class_B.method_2 as m2

 # to simplify, you have given a name for class_B.method_2 i.e 'm2'
 # So you can directly call the method

 some_variable = m2 # As we have renamed as m2
```

In your example, tkinter is the module name. ttk is one of its classes. And Style is a method(function)

So similarly,

```
# all (*) not mentioned

import tkinter


root  = tkinter.Tk()

# if all mentioned

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# specify class name while importing
from tkinter import ttk
some_variable = ttk
```

Note all the level of hierarchy can be imported with alias:

```
#Alias examples-1
import tkinter as tkr
root = tkr.Tk()

#Alias examples-2
from tkinter import Tk as t
root = t()

##Alias examples-3
from tkinter import ttk.Style as st

style = st
```

You can follow any method according to your conveniency.
But read the module's official documents in library and find out which function comes in which class.

Edit:

Though the above is the basic idea, the behaviour specification can be added when a module is written in C- language. Like certain sub-modules need to be imported specifically.

Reason for doing this is as follows:

1. Since the size of the module like tkinter is very big, by splitting this way reduces the execution time according to one's requirement.
2. During the initial phases of development They would not have expected that the modules is going to have more options and with increase in size. When the size increases over a period of time, for the sake of simplicity, they add the behaviour specification
3. Too much of namespaces lead to complexity and confusions. They call it namespace pollution.
4. C-language has an added advantage of doing this.

Comment: While I can see where you coming from and I appreciate your effort to help someone, you missed the point of the question. ttk is a so called *sub-module* and has little to do with what you have written.

Comment: Thank you @Thingamabobs. I'm sorry, Having typed this big, At one point we ended without much clarification. I thought that just mentioning to read official documents says everything. Edited now.